# Allow others to make google spreadsheet copies that retain the view/edit permissions of its parent spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet with the permission "anyone with the link can view" so that I'm the only one able to edit but people can look at it freely. I have also been giving people the https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheetID/copy link so that they automatically make their own copy of my spreadsheet and give me the link when they are done inputting. I naively assumed the permissions would be the same, but the copy is privated and requires me to request permissions to view.

How can I configure it so that they are creating a copy with the same permissions(allow anyone to view without logging in and they are the only ones able to edit)? Or if its not possible, then something like

creating a script in the parent spreadsheet that when run, creates a new copy of the spreadsheet in my google drive, and gives them or redirects them to the copy's link.

Answer (score 0):

From the OP's question

> How can I configure it so that they are creating a copy with the same permissions?

It's not possible.

> Or if its not possible, then something like
>
> creating a script in the parent spreadsheet that when run, creates a new copy of the spreadsheet in my google drive, and gives them or redirects them to the copy's link.

This is possible. You could use the Drive Service but to have more control about how the file permissions are handled you should use the Advanced Drive Service.

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive